# React.js map loop with async promise is infinite, if surrounding promise.all.then(response ... ) assigns the response value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have just now run into this issue can not find any ressources on my case exactly.
I am building a React App that uses the Spotify API and want to execute a function, that fills a local useState object with and Array of "ArtistInformation", a js Object which comes from an API endpoint.

This code example loops over an array of artist ids and is supposed to execute the Api function "spotiApi.getArtistInfo(id)" only once.

When running it like this:

```
  const getArtistInformation = () => {
    console.log("sp ids",spotifyArtistIds)
    Promise.all(spotifyArtistIds.map(id => {
      return spotiApi.getArtistInfo(id)
    })).then(respList => {
      // setArtistInfo(respList)
      console.log("artistInfo", artistInfo)})
  }
```

The Snippet runs fine and stops execution

But when the "setArtistInfo" useState call is called, the loop continues to execute infinitly

```
  const getArtistInformation = () => {
    console.log("sp ids",spotifyArtistIds)
    Promise.all(spotifyArtistIds.map(id => {
      return spotiApi.getArtistInfo(id)
    })).then(respList => {
      setArtistInfo(respList)
      console.log("artistInfo", artistInfo)})
  }
```

Here is the whole component for reference:

```
import { Box } from "@mui/material";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import SpotifyApi from "../../api/SpotifyApi";

export const DashboardView = () => {
  const spotifyArtistIds = useSelector(state => state.member.spotifyArtistIds)

  const [artistInfo, setArtistInfo] = useState([])
  const [showId, setShowId] = useState(spotifyArtistIds[0])
  const spotiApi = new SpotifyApi();

  const getArtistInformation = () => {
    console.log("sp ids",spotifyArtistIds)
    Promise.all(spotifyArtistIds.map(id => {
      return spotiApi.getArtistInfo(id)
    })).then(respList => {
      // setArtistInfo(respList)
      console.log("artistInfo", artistInfo)})
  }
 

  const getThisArtistInfo = () => {
    console.log("art", artistInfo)
    return artistInfo.filter(info => info.data.id === showId)[0].data
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    getArtistInformation()
  })

  return (
    <Box>
      <h2>{getThisArtistInfo()?.name}'s Dashboard</h2>

    </Box>)
}
```

Thank you for any help in advance and hopefully we can figure this out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *loop* doesn't execute endlessly, the component *re-renders* endlessly.  This causes a re-render:

```
setArtistInfo(respList);
```

And this executes *on every render*:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getArtistInformation();
});
```

So each render gets artist information, which triggers a re-render, which gets artist information, which triggers a re-render, etc., etc.

If the intent is to get artist information only on the *first* render, include an empty dependency array:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getArtistInformation();
}, []); // <-- here
```

Comment: I only deleted the empty dependency because my VsCode told me I was "missing a Dependency" and realised it "worked" without it... Thanks a lot, this makes so much sense!

Comment: @FelixKniest: Linters may complain that it's missing the dependency for `getArtistInformation`, which you can also add to the array.  But if you do that then you'd probably also want to wrap `getArtistInformation` in a `useCallback` hook, which will also have its own dependency array (to include things like `setArtistInfo`, etc.).